# How do I grant ASP.NET permissions to Write an Event Log entry

Tags: asp.net, logging, permissions

I am trying to write to the application event log using EventLog.WriteEntry in System.Diagnostics.

I have no problem on my local machine, but on my virtual server, it blows a security error.

I tried this with the default AppPoolIdentity, and under a custom user created for a new AppPool in the IIS_IUSR group, without success.

On advice, I gave permissions in REGEDIT to my app pool user to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\EventLog

Still no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you only adding entries to one Event Source? If so, create the source first and it should work, as the permissions are only required to create **new** event **sources**.